# How do I make sure my PC program is receiving socketio events from my phone?

Tags: c#, flutter, encryption, cryptography

I have a C# program, and a flutter application that runs on mobiles. They communicate through a python socketio server.

**The C# program and flutter app exchange data first by entering a room inside the socketio server:** I generate a random string inside the C# program and create a room with that string. Then, I scan a QR code on my phone that has that string, and the flutter app joins the same room.

Then, they start exchanging data. For example, I send a socketio event from my phone, the python server receives that event and broadcasts it to the room which my C# program picks it up and performs something (such as "stress_test" event where the C# program runs some code to stress test the RAM).

Now, I want to make sure that these events are coming from my phone and not from someone who randomly joined the room. I don't even want the server to understand what these data are, for security reasons.

**What I've tried:** use AES encryption. But I don't really know how to use it in my case...

Let's say I scan the QR code inside the app: the flutter app gets the room name and the AES passkey from the QR code. Then, I use that passkey to encrypt data and send it to the program. But what data should be encrypted? Because I'm just triggering socketio events and you can't encrypt that.

I'm really ignorant when it comes to cyber security, maybe there's a tech that I don't know about. I'd really appreciate some guidance.

EDIT: I thought about doing something else, I wanted to change every socketio event into one event (such as an "event_trigger"), and put the actual event name inside the data which is encrypted.

For example:

```
event name: event_trigger
data: *encrypted data*
```

Where the data contains the actual event.
But someone else can join the room, get the event, and re-send the data to trigger a stress test without the user's content.

Comment: You might want to consider using mutual TLS (mTLS) with python's socket object.  This way, in addition to the client authenticating the server by way of the server's certificate, the opposite takes place as well - i.e. the server authenticates the client by was of the certificate that the client presents to the server.  The server can refuse connections from any client that does not present a certificate that the server recognizes.  See https://docs.python.org/3/library/ssl.html for more info.